# Exceções em Java

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch

Estou estudando sobre exceções em Java e gostaria de entender melhor.

Ao declarar um objeto, se o programador prever que pode ocorrer uma falha na execução do método, ele lançará um objeto do tipo `Exception`. (certo?)

Queria entender como funciona a captura e lançamento da exceção.

O porquê da `RuntimeException` e suas subclasses não são verificadas pelo compilador.

Se o bloco `try/catch` é usado somente para tratar de exceções ou se existe outras finalidade de uso.

Quando um bloco `try` executa um método excepcional, no momento que o método lançar a exceção, o restante do código do método não ocorrerá junto com o restante de codigo de `try`, pulando para `catch`? Se sim e no caso de um método multi-excepcional?

E por último, o que é a classe `Throwable`?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Exceções são uma forma de **desvio**, assim como `if`s, `break`s, `return`s, etc. Sua utilidade é permitir que um código seja interrompido caso não possua condições de continuar, de forma conveniente e organizada.

Suponha que Java não possua exceções. Se o método `a` chama o método `b`, que chama o `c` que chama `FileReader.read`, o que acontece se houver um erro na leitura?

1. O método `c` tem que parar, pois não dá pra continuar sem os dados lidos. Ele retorna;
2. O método `b` tem que saber que o método `c` falhou; pra isso, `c` tem que retornar um código especial de erro - interferindo no seu valor de retorno normal - e `b` tem que testar por esse código usando um `if` (por exemplo);
3. O método `a` tem que saber que o método `b` falhou; etc.

Em algum lugar, esse erro terá de ser tratado - nem que seja no `main` (ou no `Thread.run`), para abortar o programa com código de erro. O que as exceções fazem é permitir que o fluxo de execução se desvie [quase que] diretamente pro ponto exato em que o tratamento de erro é possível, sem que o programador tenha de fazer mais nada. Mais: elas coletam e armazenam várias informações sobre o erro, como quais métodos estavam em execução e em que linha estavam, permitindo gerar um relatório que permita ao programador descobrir mais facilmente sua causa.

> Ao declarar um objeto, se o programador prever que pode ocorrer uma falha na execução do método, ele lançará um objeto do tipo `Exception`. (certo?)

Não necessariamente. Ele pode fazer isso se o erro for detectado pela sua própria lógica, e esse desvio for conveniente para o chamador. Ele pode também não lançar exceções diretamente, mas permitir que o seu código (i.e. as outras funções que esse método chama) as lance - declarando isso na sua assinatura se necessário (`throws ExceçãoX, ExceçãoY`). Ou ele pode fazer outra coisa, como retornar um código de erro, tentar tratar da exceção sozinho, logar em algum lugar... Depende do caso.

Em geral, a "coisa certa" a fazer é lançar/permitir que se lance uma exceção mesmo - talvez *unchecked* (mais sobre isso adiante). Retornar um código de erro complica a forma de chamada, e logar o erro torna mais difícil a customização do sistema (i.e. se você *não quer* que esse erro seja logado, e o método faz sozinho, à sua revelia, isso pode atrapalhar seu uso ou exigir alguma "gambiarra" pra contornar/desfazer isso). Se você não tem bons motivos pra desviar disso, não desvie: use exceções mesmo.

> Queria entender como funciona a captura e lançamento da exceção.

Voltando ao exemplo dos métodos `a`, `b` e `c`, digamos que `a` está preparado para tratar a exceção `E`, enquanto `b` não está. À medida que os métodos vão sendo chamados, os contextos de execução (i.e. variáveis locais, instrução corrente, etc) dos mesmos vão sendo colocados na pilha. Normalmente, `b` teria de executar até o final antes do controle voltar para `a`, o mesmo para `c` em relação a `b`. Mas se `c` encontra essa condição excepcional - e decide lançar `E` - acontece o seguinte:

1. `c` cria uma instância do objeto `E`, passando os parâmetros que precisar;
2. O fluxo de execução de `c` é interrompido onde está, i.e. seu código não termina de executar;
3. Se `c` possui um bloco `try/finally` ou `try/catch/finally`, e a exceção foi lançada dentro do `try`, ele executa o finally;
4. `c` é desempilhado. Normalmente, `b` continuaria executando de onde parou, mas não é isso que acontece. O processo de lançamento da exceção ainda não terminou.
5. Se `b` possui um bloco `try/finally` ou `try/catch/finally`, e `c` foi chamado dentro do `try`, ele executa o finally;
6. `b` é desempilhado. Normalmente, `a` continuaria executando de onde parou, mas o processo de lançamento da exceção ainda não terminou.
7. Como `b` foi chamado dentro de um bloco `try/catch` ou `try/catch/finally`, e `E` está presente em uma das cláusulas `catch`, esse bloco é executado.
8. O processo de lançamento de exceção terminou. O código continua do bloco `catch` pra frente.

> O porquê da `RuntimeException` e suas subclasses não são verificadas pelo compilador.

Há dois tipos de exceção: as **checadas** (*checked*) e as **não checadas** (*unchecked*). Idealmente - do ponto de vista dos projetistas de Java - nenhum método deveria se comportar de modo inesperado; ou ele deveria ter sucesso, ou falhar de forma ordenada e consistente. Como métodos normalmente chamam outros métodos, cada um deveria ser responsável por se comportar bem mesmo na presença de erros nos métodos chamados. Assim, cada método precisaria estar ciente das exceções que seus componentes podem lançar, e ou tratá-las ou propagá-las para o método chamador. Para isso ser possível, o método chamador tem de estar ciente que esse método pode lançar as exceções `X`, `Y` e `Z`, e se preparar de acordo.

Na teoria é uma beleza, mas na prática isso é inviável. Há erros que podem ocorrer em qualquer método, e seria um desperdício ficar declarando eles a toda hora. A memória da JVM pode acabar, por exemplo. Ou numa divisão, o divisor pode ser zero. Se fôssemos levar em conta todas essas possibilidades, a assinatura dos nossos métodos ia ficar gigantesca! E pra piorar as coisas, é muito pouco provável que o método chamador seja capaz de se recuperar de, digamos, um `OutOfMemoryError` - qualquer coisa que ele tentasse fazer ia gastar mais memória e gerar *outro* `OutOfMemoryError`, virando uma bola de neve...

Para isso é que existem as exceções *unchecked*: para **desobrigar** os métodos de declararem que essa exceção é possível, mas ainda permitir que algum deles tente tratá-la se achar que dá conta. A `RuntimeException` é a classe base para todas elas, exceto pelo `Error` - que em geral denota uma condição mais grave que dificilmente poderá ser tratada por método algum.

Obs.: é melhor usar exceções *checked* (que herda de `Exception`) ou *unchecked* (que herda de `RuntimeException`)? Não sei te dizer. É um balanço entre a segurança do código e a sua concisão/expressividade. `try/catch`es demais e seu código fica ilegível, `try/catch`es de menos e ninguém sabe mais que erros podem ocorrer num método. É uma situação semelhante a se usar tipagem estática (com ou sem tipos genéricos) vs. *duck typing* vs. tipagem dinâmica: ganha-se de um lado e perde-se do outro...

> Se o bloco try/catch é usado somente para tratar de exceções ou se existe outras finalidade de uso.

Teoricamente você poderia [ab]usá-lo para se simular um `goto`, mas em geral não, é só pra tratar de exceções mesmo. Cabe notar que em Java o tratamento de exceções é relativamente caro, de modo que muitas vezes é preferível se usar fluxos de controle "normais" mesmo [para códigos não excepcionais], ainda que isso complique um pouco seu código. Outras linguagens (ex.: Python) já os usa para situações mais corriqueiras - por exemplo a expressão idiomática (*idiom*) "não verifique os parâmetros antes de chamar a função, simplesmente a chame e se não tiver sucesso capture a exceção". Deve-se evitar isso em Java (mesmo porquê `try/catch`es não são exatamente concisos na minha opinião...).

Já o `try/finally` e o `try/catch/finally`, também é usado para lidar com exceções, mesmo que não exatamente para "tratá-las". Considere esse código:

```
try {
    String linha = leitor.readLine();
    int x = Integer.parseInt(linha);
}
catch(IOException ioe) { ... }
finally {
    leitor.close();
}
```

Nesse caso, queremos que o leitor seja fechado não importa o que aconteça: se o código for bem-sucedido, se ele lançar uma `IOException`, ou se ele lançar outra exceção qualquer. O importante é não esquecê-lo aberto. Pois mesmo se um `NumberFormatException` for lançado no `try`, e ele nem chegar a entrar no `catch`, o `finally` ainda vai executar (antes da exceção se propagar para o método chamador).

> ...e no caso de um método multi-excepcional?

Como já foi dito, o código do `try` (ou todo o código do método, se a exceção ocorrer fora de um `try`) é interrompido ao ocorrer uma exceção, saltando para um `catch` ou um `finally`. Se ele cair num `catch`, então considera-se que o tratamento da exceção foi feito com sucesso, e o código do bloco `catch` é tratado como um código normal - podendo inclusive lançar outra exceção, sem relação alguma com a exceção original.

Se ele cair num `finally`, por outro lado, temos um problema: o `finally` não é o "destino" da exceção, somente um "ponto de parada". Se ele *também* produzir um erro, qual deve ir pro método chamador - o original ou o novo? A solução que o Java dá para esse impasse é a seguinte: o método novo é lançado, mas a exceção guarda uma referência à exceção original. Diz-se nesse caso que a exceção `B` foi "causada por" a exceção `A`. Pode-se acessar `A` através de `B.getCause()`. Nesse caso, é importante frisar que o método chamador precisa tratar de `B` - se ele só tratar de `A`, a execução não vai entrar no bloco `catch`.

> E por último o que é a classe `Throwable`?

Como já dito, há dois tipos de "erros" em Java: `Error`s e `Exception`s. A classe `Throwable` é a superclasse de ambos, criada para permitir código que trate dos dois simultaneamente. Programadores "normais" em geral não devem tentar tratar `Error` - uma vez que se trata de uma falha grave que só será contornada se você souber bem o que está fazendo. Por isso, não há sentido em se usar `catch Throwable` - é melhor pegar somente `Exception` mesmo (se for um código genérico de tratamento de erros) ou, melhor ainda, pegar só as exceções que você consegue mesmo tratar (e propagar todo o resto).

---

Algumas referências (em inglês):

- [Chained Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/chained.html) (sobre exceções causadas por outras exceções)
- [Unchecked Exceptions - The Controversy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) (sobre usar ou não exceções *unchecked* no seu código - obviamente, os autores de Java pendem pro lado da segurança em detrimento da concisão; outros discordam)

Comment: Meio ampla a pergunta, mas tentei responder da melhor forma que pude. Se tiver dúvidas em algum ponto específico, sugiro abrir uma nova pergunta, mais focada, onde haja espaço para uma resposta mais detalhada.

Comment: Obrigado! Realmente não sabia que seria tão extensa a resposta. Preciso pesquisar sobre alguns pontos que você citou em sua resposta para eu poder entende-la melhor. Se eu precisar novamente de auxilio, irei solicitar aqui, com o link da nova pergunta, para que você possa dar continuidade em sua resposta. Mais uma vez agradeço sua atenção :)

Comment: [Minha nova pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27615/fluxo-de-execu%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-um-bloco-try-catch-finally) Gostaria que você pudesse dar uma olhada!

Comment: Um artigo que achei muito bom sobre quando usar _checked_ ou _unchecked exceptions_ é esse aqui: [http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2003/11/19/exceptions.html)