# Fluxo de execução de um bloco try/catch/finally

Tags: java, exceção, try-catch, try-finally

Como funciona o fluxo de execução em um bloco `try/catch/finally` no exemplo abaixo?

```
public class ExceptionTest {

    public static void makeException() throws ExceptionAlpha, ExceptionBeta, ExceptionGamma {

        throw new ExceptionBeta();    

    }

    public static void main(String [] args) {

        try {

            makeException();
            System.out.println("Isto não vai ser executado.");

        } catch(ExceptionAlpha alphaEx) {

            System.out.println("Exceção Alpha foi lançada.");

        } catch(ExceptionBeta betaEx) {

            System.out.println("Exceção Beta foi lançada.");

        } catch(ExceptionGamma gammaEx) {

            System.out.println("Exceção Gamma foi lançada.");

        } finally {

            System.out.println("Isto será executado, independente se houver exceções.");

        }

    }

}
```

Existe a possibilidade de se usar operadores lógicos em catch? por exemplo: `catch(ExceptionAlpha alphaEx && ExceptionBeta betaEx) {...}`

Queria saber também, neste mesmo código, como fazer para se lançar mais de uma exceção, além da `ExceptionBeta` e como seria o fluxo de execução do código.

Obrigado!

Comment: É mais uma opinião pessoal mas eu prefiro usar exceções só pra "cascar fora" e abortar o programa inteiro. Quando você começa a capturar exceções, em especial capturar exceções em padrões complicados fica bem difícil prever qual é o fluxo de execução que o seu programa realmente vai tomar e garantir que você não deixou nenhum objeto com um estado interno inválido...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Como funciona o fluxo de execução em um bloco try/catch/finally no exemplo abaixo?

Você vai entrar no try e jogar uma exceção. Como previsto, o println depois de `makeException()` não vai ser executado. Depois disso, programa vai executar o bloco `catch(ExceptionBeta` e depois disso o bloco dentro do `finally`.

O bloco finally sempre executa no final, independentemente de uma exceção ter sido lançada ou não (ele é particularmente útil para fazer a "limpeza" no final do método)

> Queria saber também, neste mesmo código, como fazer para se lançar mais de uma exceção, além da ExceptionBeta

Em Java, e em todas as linguagens de programação que conheço com exceções, só dá pra lançar uma exceção de cada vez.

Uma possibilidade é criar uma única classe para a exceção e passar a lista de erros como um dos campos dessa classe.

> Existe a possibilidade de se usar operadores lógicos em catch? por exemplo: catch(ExceptionAlpha alphaEx && ExceptionBeta betaEx) {...}

Não sei o que você espera que o && faça nesse caso. De qualquer forma, não acho que Java suporta algo do gênero.

Quanto ao "ou", para tratar mais de um tipo de exceção em um único catch, em Java 7+ existe a sintaxe `|` para isso:

```
catch (IOException|SQLException ex) {
    logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html

Se você estiver com uma versão mais antiga do Java, o melhor que você pode fazer é capturar uma superclasse das suas classes ou fazer vários catchs mesmo. Nesse último caso você pode tentar criar um medotozinho interno para evitar duplicar código.

```
} catch(ExceptionAlpha alphaEx) { 
    tratarExcecao();
} catch(ExceptionBeta betaEx) {
    tratarExcecao();
}
```

Comment: Entendi! Muito obrigado!

Comment: Qual o sentido de usar `throw ex`? Não seria muito mais simples colocar `throws` no método?

Comment: Nesse caso é porque estou dando um log antes de relançar a exceção.