# Como criar uma Exception/Exceção customizada em Java

Tags: java, java-ee, exceção

Java, traz consigo diversas Exceptions já prontas, IllegalArgumentException, IllegalStateException, RuntimeException, entre outras.

Como criar uma Exceção Customizada em Java?

Tenho o seguinte método - `sumAndPrint(int,int)`

Soma dois inteiros e printa eles para o Output associado ao System.

```
public void sumAndPrint(int x, int y) throws Exception{
        if(x < 0 || y < 0){
            //trocar uma excessao específica - NumeroNegativoException
            throw new Exception("Numeros negativos nao permitidos");
        }
        System.out.println("soma -> " + (x+y));
    }
```

Contudo, não aceito como argumentos valores menores que zero.

**Quero criar minha própria exceção(checked exception) - `NumeroNegativoException` - como faço isso?**

> O objetivo desta pergunta/resposta é compartilhar conhecimento sobre
>   como criar exceções em Java.

Comment: Não crie excepções só porque quer um nome mais especifico. No caso do seu exemplo use `IllegalArgumentException` porque é disso que se trata.

Comment: Esta questão tem o propósito de compartilhar conhecimento de como criar . Este é só um exemplo @ramaral

Comment: Dica: "Exceção" se escreve com "ç", e não com "ss".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Criar exceções customizadas em Java, é perfeitamente possível, e esta prática é usada largamente por diversos frameworks, como Hibernate, Spring, Struts entre outros vários.

O idioma para criacão de Exceções é o seguinte:

```
class NumeroNegativoException extends Exception  /* RuntimeException */{
    /**
     * importante caso a exceção seja serializada
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1149241039409861914L;

    // constrói um objeto NumeroNegativoException com a mensagem passada por parâmetro
    public NumeroNegativoException(String msg){
        super(msg);
    }

    // contrói um objeto NumeroNegativoException com mensagem e a causa dessa exceção, utilizado para encadear exceptions
    public NumeroNegativoException(String msg, Throwable cause){
        super(msg, cause);
    }
}
```

**Pontos importantes:**

- Para criar a mesma exceção acima, mas como uma RuntimeException, também chamada de unchecked exception, basta herdar a classe RuntimeException ao 
  invés de Exception
- Neste exemplo estamos sobreescrevendo tanto o construtor `Exception(String)` quanto `Exception(String,Throwable)`. Por que? Java permite que encadeemos exceções, dizendo que uma excessão foi causada por outra exceção, o termo técnico para este caso é *chaining exceptions*. Por isso precisamos do construtor `Exception(String,Throwable)`, onde o throwable é o a causa.
- Pela estrutura de herança tanto um checked exceptions quanto unchecked exceptios são objetos serializáveis, ou seja, implementam a interface `Serializable`. Portanto, pode ser útil definir o campo *serialVersionID*, mas não obrigatório, o compilador apenas lançará um Warning.

Esta pergunta/resposta está associada com esta outra: [Exceções em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27529/exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-java)

Recomendo a leitura para um completo entendimento de Exceções em Java, caso o leitor não saiba o que os termos encadeamento, checked, unchecked significam.