# Código com JDBC falha com exceção

Tags: java, banco-de-dados, jdbc, arraylist

Estou tentando realizar uma pesquisa no banco de dados através do java.

Estou utilizando esse código, mas esta entrando na exceção:

```
public ArrayList<Pessoas> pesquisar(String nome) {
    ArrayList<Pessoas> lista = new ArrayList<Pessoas>();
    try(Connection con = new MySql().conecta()) {

        String sql = "select *"+
        " from pessoas"+
        "where nome like '%?%'";

        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setString(1, nome);

        java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);


        while (rs.next()){

        Pessoas pesquisa = new Pessoas();
        pesquisa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        pesquisa.setDataNasc(rs.getString("dataNasc"));
        pesquisa.setTipo(TIPO.valueOf(rs.getString("sexo")));
        pesquisa.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        pesquisa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
        pesquisa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
        pesquisa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
        pesquisa.setNumCasa(rs.getString("numCasa"));
        pesquisa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
        pesquisa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
        pesquisa.setCep(rs.getString("cep"));
        pesquisa.setEstado(rs.getString("estado"));
        pesquisa.setObservacao(rs.getString("observacao"));

        // adicionando o objeto à lista
        lista.add(pesquisa);


        }

        rs.close();
        stmt.execute();
        stmt.close();

    } catch(SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("teste15");

    }
    return lista;

}
```

Comment: Esse  `System.out.println("teste15");` não serve pra nada nesse código, não ajuda a entender porque caiu no catch. Logo, remova isso, e troque por `e.printStackTrace();` que é o que realmente irá mostrar o motivo.

Comment: Então tire o `try-catch` para ver a exceção acontecer. Eu costumo dizer que meus código raramente passam de meia dúzia de `try-catch`, eu não entendo porque as pessoas enchem disso no código, captura exceção quase sempre deixa o código menos robusto e não mais.

Comment: @Maniero a exceção é checada, e as malditas IDEs indicam essa solução pra "resolver o problema" da exceção checada. Com uma boa intenção, a IDE acaba induzindo quem tá aprendendo a fazer uma coisa sem fazer ideia do que está fazendo.

Comment: De qualquer sorte, se você tivesse um pouco mais de cuidado e posto um espaço depois do nome da tabela ou um espaço antes do `where` você não teria gerado erro ao preparar consulta

Answer (score 3):

Em primeiro lugar, o [**princípio da inversão de dependências**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) diz que deve codificar-se para abstrações, e não para implementações. Uma aplicação bem direta desse princípio seria usar `List` ao invés de `ArrayList`.

Segundo, você já está usando o *try-with-resources* no seu `Connection`, mas é importante usá-lo adequadamente no `PreparedStatement` e no `ResultSet` também.

Terceiro, use a sintaxe do diamante sempre que possível.

Quarto, prefira usar nomes de classes sempre no singular.

Quinto, a sintaxe do seu SQL está errada. Você não deve colocar o `?` dentro de aspas.

Sexto, ou você deve tratar as exceções adequadamente ou relançar. Não fazer nenhum dos dois é sempre uma má prática de programação que vai lhe ocultar os erros.

Sétimo, você tem um `stmt.execute();` sobrando de bobeira no final.

Oitavo, você estava executando a SQL em dois lugares diferentes, com `con.prepareStatement(sql)` e com `stmt.executeQuery(sql)`. Substitua a segunda forma por `stmt.executeQuery()`.

Nono, nomes de classes não devem ser escritos em letras apenas maiúsculas (`TIPO`). Use `Tipo`. Veja mais sobre isso [**nessa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/153555/132).

Eis o seu código revisado:

```
private static final String SELECT_SQL = "SELECT * FROM Pessoas WHERE nome LIKE ?";

public List<Pessoa> pesquisar(String nome) {
    try (
        Connection con = new MySql().conecta();
        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(SELECT_SQL))
    {
        stmt.setString(1, "%" + nome + "%");

        try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
            List<Pessoa> lista = new ArrayList<>();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Pessoa pesquisa = new Pessoa();
                pesquisa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
                pesquisa.setDataNasc(rs.getString("dataNasc"));
                pesquisa.setTipo(Tipo.valueOf(rs.getString("sexo")));
                pesquisa.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
                pesquisa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
                pesquisa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
                pesquisa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
                pesquisa.setNumCasa(rs.getString("numCasa"));
                pesquisa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
                pesquisa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
                pesquisa.setCep(rs.getString("cep"));
                pesquisa.setEstado(rs.getString("estado"));
                pesquisa.setObservacao(rs.getString("observacao"));

                // adicionando o objeto à lista
                lista.add(pesquisa);
            }
            return lista;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Uma possível melhoria seria revisar a forma de se instanciar `Pessoa`. Leia [**essa resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/252986/132) para maiores informações acerca disso.

Além disso, tenho certeza que esse `new MySql().conecta()` poderia ser feito de alguma outra forma melhor.

Answer (score 0):

Não use SQLException no catch pois ele vai exibir somente exceções do tipo SQLException e esconder todas as outras, só vale a pena escolher o tipo de exceção se você for tratar ela.

Faça um teste e se der exception novamente trás da ROOT CAUSE aqui!

```
public ArrayList<Pessoas> pesquisar(String nome) {
    ArrayList<Pessoas> lista = new ArrayList<Pessoas>();

    try {
        Connection con = new MySql().conecta()

        String sql = "select *"+
        " from pessoas"+
        "where nome like '%?%'";

        PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        stmt.setString(1, nome);

        // trabalhe com PreparedStatement assim!
        stmt.executeQuery();
        java.sql.ResultSet rs = stmt.getResultSet();


        while (rs.next()){

        Pessoas pesquisa = new Pessoas();
        pesquisa.setNome(rs.getString("nome"));
        pesquisa.setDataNasc(rs.getString("dataNasc"));
        pesquisa.setTipo(TIPO.valueOf(rs.getString("sexo")));
        pesquisa.setEmail(rs.getString("email"));
        pesquisa.setCelular(rs.getString("celular"));
        pesquisa.setTelefone(rs.getString("telefone"));
        pesquisa.setEndereco(rs.getString("endereco"));
        pesquisa.setNumCasa(rs.getString("numCasa"));
        pesquisa.setBairro(rs.getString("bairro"));
        pesquisa.setCidade(rs.getString("cidade"));
        pesquisa.setCep(rs.getString("cep"));
        pesquisa.setEstado(rs.getString("estado"));
        pesquisa.setObservacao(rs.getString("observacao"));

        // adicionando o objeto à lista
        lista.add(pesquisa);


        }

        rs.close();
        //stmt.execute(); não precisa disso
        stmt.close();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return lista;

}
```

Esta pergunta/resposta está associada com esta outra: [Exceções em Java](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/27529/exce%C3%A7%C3%B5es-em-java)

Recomendo a leitura para um melhor entendimento.

Comment: A falta do espaço entre o nome da tabela `pessoas` e a palavra chave `where` continua gerando erro de sintaxe no SQL, a String sendo preparada é a absurda "`select * from pessoaswhere nome like '%?%'`"