# Diferença entre Error - Exception - Throwable dentro do catch()

Tags: exceção, try-catch

Sempre quando eu tratava o `catch` eu usava `(Exception e)` porém a alguns dias atras me deparei com uma exceção que não se encaixava no `catch (Exception e)` então descobri que ela na verdade não é uma exceção mas sim um erro. Logo então passei a suar `catch (Error | Exception e)` porém hoje me deparei com um código que usa apenas `catch (Throwable e)`.

Então gostaria de saber a diferença entre esses termos, ou, não sei como posso chamá-los.

Comment: Entre no tópico do Uso específico do try-catch e não encontrei nada falando sobre Error, no final das contas acabei achando outros tópicos a respeito que mais ou menos resolveram minha questão, mas sinceramente não acho que minha pergunta seja duplicata desta que você marcou as duvidas são bem diferentes.

Comment: De qual linguagem de programação você está falando? Há um mais do que uma linguagem que tem `Exception` e `Throwable`, mas as regras variam de uma para outra.

Comment: Eu trabalho com java, mas achei que as regras da explicação fossem as mesmas para a maioria das outras linguagens.

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi tanto o `Error` quanto a `Exception` implementam a interface `Throwable` então se eu fiz um `catch (Throwable e)` eu irei capturar todos os objetos lançáveis que no caso são as exceções e erros, entretendo se eu um `catch (Exception e)` eu irei capturar todas os objetos lançáveis do tipo `Exception` e se eu fizer `catch (Error e)` eu irei capturar todos os objetos lançáveis do tipo `Error`. Esta certa a lógica?

Comment: Em Java, `Throwable` é uma classe, e não uma interface. Você recebeu uma resposta sobre PHP porque você não disse sobre qual linguagem estava falando e um amigo aí achou que podia ser PHP. Isso também significou que a sua pergunta estava confusa e mal-elaborada, e portanto foi fechada (afinal de contas, não estava claro sobre qual linguagem você estava falando). Agora, sabendo que a sua pergunta era sobre Java, ela talvez seja uma duplicata [desta outra pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/27529/132).

Answer (score 1):

**Throwable** é a interface base para qualquer objeto lançável.

> Fonte: [PHP - Throwable](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.throwable.php)

**Exception** é a classe base para todas *Exceptions* no *PHP 5*, e a classe base de todas as exceções de usuário no *PHP 7*.

> Fonte: [PHP - Exception](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.exception.php)

Em resumo, a capturar a *interface* é equivalente a capturar todas as classes que a implementam...

> *- não sei como posso chamá-los*

Imagine o seguinte cenário: você [estende a classe](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.extending.php) `\Exception` no seu projeto e, quando quiser parar a execução de algo e simplesmente exibir a mensagem, lança essa classe. Mas caso ocorra algum erro fatal, exceção literal, e etc, você exibe a mensagem do erro e encerra a execução total do script. Exemplo:

```
<?php

try {
    bar();
    if (!baz())
        throw new MinhaExcecao('A função baz() retornou falso.');
} catch (MinhaExcecao $e) {
    echo $e -> getMessage();
    // O script vai continuar a ser executado...
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('PDO lançou uma exceção. Há algo errado na conexão/consulta do banco de dados.');
    // O script não vai continuar a ser executado...
} catch (Throwable $e) {
    die('Capturado alguma classe que implementa a interface Throwable');
    // O script não vai continuar a ser executado...
}

echo 'foo';
```

Se a função `baz()` retornar falso, vai cair no bloco `catch (MinhaExcecao $e)` com o `echo` e logo o script vai continuar no `echo 'foo';`... Nos outros casos, a execução será totalmente interrompida pela chamada da função `die()`.

Vale lembrar que os `catch` funcionam como uma cascata. Ao lançar algum objeto, ele vai ser capturado no primeiro bloco `catch` compatível com a classe/interface lançada. Dessa forma, sua classe personalizada deve ser capturada primeiro ou antes de sua classe/interface pai, ou então não vai chegar no `catch` pretendido.

Ainda existe o bloco *[finally](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php#language.exceptions.finally)* que, teoricamente, SEMPRE é executado.

Estender a classe `\Exception` é muito útil quando você quer passar alguma mensagem de erro para o usuário a qual ele fez algo de errado. As demais mensagens costumam ser erros do programador ou algum recurso que não está trabalhando da forma adequada. Daí é melhor você gerar um *log* acessível apenas a você (admin/dev). O usuário não precisa saber o motivo ou onde ocorrem tais erros. Logicamente que seria bem útil dizer algo do tipo: "*Este recurso apresentou um erro*", mas sem detalhar...

Outro exemplo típico é a conexão com o banco de dados com *PHP* via *PDO* que exibe os dados explicitamente quando não estão em um bloco `try` / `catch` adequado:

[image: Erro PDO/PHP]

Utilizei o *PHP* como referência, mas a teoria é equivalente nas principais linguagens de programação. Talvez há algumas pequenas diferenças...

Comment: Pelo que eu entendi tanto o Error quanto o Exception estendem o Throwable é isso? Então se eu colocar catch (Throwable e) eu iriei capturar qualquer exceção ou erro gerado? Sobre a questão das exceções 'próprias' eu já tinha estudado um pouco a respeito, mas mesmo assim obrigado ajudo a clarear ainda mais.

Comment: Sim, mas o certo seria dizer que elas **implementam** a interface Throwable. E, logicamente, você deve capturar cada tipo de exceção em seu devido lugar...

Comment: Sim, eu confundi a palavra estender com implementar, na maioria dos casos eu trabalho cada exceção separadamente porém, em alguns casos, é bem melhor capturar tudo de uma vez. Obrigado pela explicação.